# Full calendar and Laravel load error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-5

I am trying to use full calendar from http://fullcalendar.io/ in combination with the laravel framework but When I try to show the calendar on my page, it doesn't show.

The error I am getting is in my javascript:

```
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

The code and HTML I am using is:

```
@extends('app')

@section('scripts')
<script src='/proofofconcept/fullcalendar-2.3.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/proofofconcept/fullcalendar-2.3.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/proofofconcept/fullcalendar-2.3.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<script src="/proofofconcept/fullcalendar-2.3.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='/proofofconcept/fullcalendar-2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Calendar</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I have followed the basic usage guide on http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ but I must have done something wrong because it's not doing what it's supposed to

Comment: Are you getting any 404s in the console for `JS` files?

Comment: no, all of the js files are accounted for, 
I'm getting some 'declaration ignored' warnings on the css page for fullcalendar though

Comment: Try assigning your element to a variable first: `var calendar = $('#calendar'); calendar.fullCalendar(...)`

Comment: I have tried that before, it gives me the same error except now it says 
calendar.fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: @JeremyC. Why do you call the JS file twice? First the full version and then the minified one?

Comment: to be completely honest it is because I am really new at this and I didn't even notice that they were the same file :p I tried again by removing the minified one and then once again re-adding the minified and removing the full version and I still get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my 'app' page to which this part of the code : `@extends('app')` refers, I had a reference to another minified version of jquery which seemed to be conflicting with the minified jquery file I was including in my script tags

Answer (score 0):

Updated one

```
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    });
});
```

If the above code works then download the js files used in script tag

Comment: calling it from a different function does not solve the problem, also I don't really know what all those variables are yet as I am still trying to get the basic usage to work so I don't know which options I will need and which I don't also it doesnt really matter because it only gets as far as this: 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');

Comment: just try this alone.. $('#calendar').fullCalendar({  });

Comment: that still produces the same problem

Comment: This still gives me the same message as before

Comment: do you have any other idea as to how I can fix this? (sorry for late answer but I only started working on project again today)

Comment: this code works for me fine.. I think some other thing in your site causing issue. 1. place a debugger inside ready function and try it. 2. check "viewsource" whether all the files are attached.. Else start fresh..

Comment: chinja I found the issue, I was loading in a different version of jquery in my 'app' page which conflicted the first version, removed it and now it runs smoothly, sorry for bothering you again